# maven-dependency-plugin 3.6.+ started to find new 'Used undeclared dependencies found' during dependency:analyze goal

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to migrate a project from java 11 to 21, for this i need to update the dependency plugin from 3.1.2 to 3.6.+ (the lower one doesn't support 21)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version> -> to 3.6.1
    <configuration>
       <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
       <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But I've found that seems 3.6.+ work a bit differently (**even with java 11**) it started to find multiple of new "Used undeclared dependencies"

```
16:42:43:965 [main] [ERROR] Used undeclared dependencies found:
16:42:43:965 [main] [ERROR]    org.springframework:enter code herespring-web:jar:5.3.30:compile
```

As I know it analyzes a compiled bytecode to find the 'Used undeclared dependencies', but it's wrong: there are no any imports in compiled classes from those libs it found.

I can't get why it happens so? Is it plugin bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Have anybody experienced something like this?

[Here is a full reproducible repo](https://github.com/DmitryTen/SO-mvn-question) of this problem

Comment: There are several options here. First the import alone is not enough it could be used via DI/service SPI/ also the plugin could have a bug sure ... but without the full build setup and the code it's impossilbe to even guess...

Comment: I've created a mini-repo to reproduce this issue, could you shortly take a look?
https://github.com/DmitryTen/SO-mvn-question
Thank you

Comment: The tag `<excludeTransitive>` does not exist... Second it is showing that because `AppRoleAuthentication` class has imports to `import org.springframework.web.client.*` and `org.springframework.http.*` which are part of `org.springframework:spring-web`. This change happens in maven-dependency-plugin version 3.6.0 but not before. The web dependency is used by `AppRoleAuthentication` which is used directly by your class `StandaloneVaultConfig`. I would see that as a bug in the plugin... I have created a bug for Maven Dependency Plugin https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-891

Comment: let me ask, what do you mean by "The tag <excludeTransitive> does not exist" ?
It's actually described in plugin.xml as "<name>excludeTransitive</name>
<description>If we should exclude transitive dependencies</description>"
Am i misunderstand smth?

Comment: The docs https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-only-mojo.html contains nothing like this... The goal https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html on the other has that... To "exclude" you have to defined as "ignored" via https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-only-mojo.html#ignoredDependencies

Answer (score 2):

You can circumvent that problem by using a different versions of the `maven-dependency-analyzer` like the following:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-analyzer</artifactId>
                        <version>1.13.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>analyze-dependencies</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>analyze-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work for java-11, but unfortunately the maven-dependency-analyzer:1.13.0 doesn't support java-21, so seems i need to wait a plugin bugfix.

Comment: @DmitriyTen Can you please show the issue, because I can run it with JDK 21...exactly in the above constalation...

Comment: okay, in my repo i've added a branch: 'fix_attempt', where i've edited the pom.xml according to your advices. And i've added 'mvn_install.log' and 'mvn_version.txt'.
Maybe this could help.

Comment: I have created a PR for your git repo.. I've seen that you are using a lot of old plugin versions and not defined them. I strongly recommend to do that... for all plugins...

Comment: i've merged your PR, but after i set <maven.compiler.release> to
21 (in your PR it's 11), it still failing on my environment, same error: 08:39:20:712 [main] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.6.1:analyze-only (analyze-dependencies) on project test: Execution analyze-dependencies of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.6.1:analyze-only failed: Unsupported class file major version 65 -> [Help 1]

Comment: Put a full log output in the repo so I can take a look into it...

Comment: pushed to main branch

Comment: btw, i've found release notes for dependency-analyzer 2.13.0. It says it only supports java 19 (which is true, with 19 it does works on my env) https://blogsarchive.apache.org/maven/entry/maven-dependency-analyzer-version-1

Comment: Outch I should have remember that, becase I wrote that... What you can try to add a newer dependency of asm in the plugin dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently working on the upgrade from java 17 to java 21. I upgraded the maven-dependency-plugin to version 3.6.1, and I currently face the same error: `[ERROR] Used undeclared dependencies found: ...`.

2 workarounds that work are to either:

- Add `ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies` or `ignoredDependencies` to the configuration of the maven-dependency-plugin. Here is a link that provides more details: https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/exclude-dependencies-from-dependency-analysis.html
- Manually declare the dependency even thought you are not explictly using it